# Is there a way i can track which IIS server redirects are being used

Tags: iis, redirect, 301-redirect, web.config

Our web.config file has 1300 redirects in it and growing all the time. Its a mixture of 4 site rebuilds over 15 years and marketing vanity URLS. My question is 3 part.

1. does having to search through 1300 redirects every time a vanity url is used impact performance in any meaningful way. Im sure it does, but is that so many its slowing things down.
2. How can i track over time which ones are actually being used. Im sure some that are over 10 years old probably never get used. i reckon i could cut the number down by 60% as they never get used anymore.
3. Is it worth doing?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: are you using native IIS Redirects, or URL Rewrite?

Comment: Last time I came in contact with IIS (what's in a name, eh?) it had access logs almost like Apache.  Shouldn't be hard to extract some statistics from those.  Put the most requested first in your redirect list.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to comment. Im not sure the difference. Im doing it like this : 'code' <add wildcard="/ed" destination="http://teachingcareers.englishfirst.com/graduate-jobs-in-china-package/?utm_source=ed&amp;utm_medium=b2b&amp;utm_campaign=teflagent&amp;utm_term=uk&amp;source=external"/>

Comment: Use Log Parser to go over the 301 responses in IIS log files. That might help you know which rules are still in use.